# Does System.IO.File.AppendAllText read the complete target file before appending?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using  `System.IO.File.AppendAllText` to append text to a log file on a network drive that is connected to a server on a remote office location (hundreds of km away). There is a VPN connection between both offices to share this drive.

Does the `StreamWriter` object that this method uses read the whole target file before appending?

Should I expect to run into performance issues as the target log file grows?

Comment: The method uses a StreamWriter. Maybe the .NET reference source code can hel you: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,1169

Comment: No, it appends by simply moving the write location to the end of the file.